# Is it possible to ignore only certain error codes for entire files in Flake8?

Tags: python, pep8, flake8

I'm editing a Django settings file that looks similar to the following:

```
# flake8: noqa
from lucy.settings.base import *
from lucy.settings.staging_production import *

# This ensures that errors from staging are tagged accordingly in Airbrake's console
AIRBRAKE.update(environment='staging')

LOGGING['handlers'].update(console={
    'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
})
```

This setting `lucy/settings/staging.py`, extends two other ones and I'd like to keep the 'star imports', so I'd like to ignore error codes `E403` and `E405` for this file.

However, the only way I see to do that is to add the `#noqa: E403, E405` comment to every line that it applies; by writing `# flake8: noqa` at the top of the file, it ignores *all* errors.

As far as I can tell from http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/3.1.1/user/ignoring-errors.html, it isn't possible to do this, or have I overlooked something?

Comment: Normally you do this by using a configuration file, or by writing a script (or `setup.py` handler, or whatever) that runs different `flake8` commands on different sets of input files. As far as I know, there's no way to do what you're trying to do—although it doesn't seem to be an entirely unreasonable request, so you might want to consider filing a feature request. (But first, is there a reason you're using the 3.1.1 docs instead of the current 3.5 docs? They're probably not likely to accept a feature request from someone who's using a 2-year-old version and not willing to upgrade…)

Comment: Also: "… the only way I see to do that is to add the #noqa: E403, E405 comment to every line that it applies …". That's only two lines right at the top of your file in your example. And, even in a larger example, it's unlikely that you're going to be using dozens and dozens of star imports, or scattering them all around your file. So is this really a problem that needs to be fixed in the first place?

Comment: I have always looked for this optionality and never found it.  In Pylint it is as simple as `pylint disable=E501,...`.

Comment: Regarding the applicability of the E403 and E405, I believe the former is raised for star imports, and the latter is raised if you for example `.update()` something that hasn't been defined or imported before. So errors were being raised for every line in the example file, not just the first two.

Answer (score 8):

Starting with Flake8 3.7.0, you can ignore specific warnings for entire files using the [`--per-file-ignores`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html?highlight=per-file-ignores#cmdoption-flake8-per-file-ignores) option.

Command-line usage:

```
flake8 --per-file-ignores='project/__init__.py:F401,F403 setup.py:E121'
```

This can also be specified in a [config file](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html):

```
[flake8]
per-file-ignores =
    __init__.py: F401,F403
    setup.py: E121
    other/*: W9
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of specifying that in the file itself, as far as I'm concerned - but you can ignore these errors when triggering flake:

```
flake8 --ignore=E403,E405 lucy/settings/staging.py
```